# Maven (multimodule project) - Copy file between modules

Tags: java, maven, file, copy, multi-module

I have a multimodule maven project, as follows:

```
module: project-assembly;
module: project-implementation;
module: project-application;
module: project-web;
```

in project-assembly/src/main/assembly/config
i have important configuration files for my project, and i need them to be copied during build process into project-web module into WEB-INF folder.

More important, this has to be done with specific profile.

For example, having a "x" profile, this is the one who needs this files in order to package successfully the project.

is there a way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Simplest solution is to put the config directory into the project-web module under src/main/resources ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the maven-antrun-plugin to copy files between arbitrary folders (ant copy). But I would strongly advise against copying between modules. It is confusing and even more: The build order or the subset of modules that are built are subject to change (depending on the dependencies and also the command line parameters). For this copying, you need to make sure that the build happens in a defined order.

Think about sharing the configuration in another way.

Comment: Unfortunately, i am not allowed to change this structure... Can you provide an example for me please?

Answer (score 1):

you can use maven resource plugin-

```
<properties> 
<othermodule-dir>...</othermodule-dir>

</properties>

<build>
 <resources>
    <resource>
      <!-- package thumbnail -->
      <directory>${sourceDir}</directory>
      <targetPath>${othermodule-dir}</targetPath>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
.
.
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what about the profile setting needed?